# Installation of Remastersys in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 16.04lts and want to install Remastersys. Pl. show me the answer who is using it.

Comment: You do realize that Ubantu is an official misspelling? :D http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15687/518562

Answer (score 2):

According to the www.remastersys.org

> Since Remastersys was abandoned, the team formed a fork Respin. Free Software and Open Source developers working together to create a FOSS
>   remastering or respin program.

Follow these steps to install Respin on your system

**Step 1:** Clone Debian and Ubuntu source code and .deb packages from git hub by executing following command. The source and .deb packages get downloaded into your present terminal working directory

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/remastersys/LinuxRespin
```

**Step 2:** Change the terminal working directory to where Ubuntu source and .deb package are located(LinuxRespin/ubuntu) and run the following command to install the package

```
sudo dpkg -i respin_1.1.0-1_all.deb
```

If you get any dependency errors after running the command in step 2, run the below command to fix the dependencies and install the package.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**note:** No need to run the command in step 2 for installing the package after running the `apt-get install -f` command, which does two jobs of fixing dependenies and also installing the package

Answer (score 1):

Download it [here](https://github.com/ch1x0r/LinuxRespin/blob/master/ubuntu/respin_1.1.0-1_all.deb), and open the downloaded file with the default program, which should be the installer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current development on Remastersys. There is a fork however called Respin.

The deb files for Respin can be downloaded from the master branch [here](https://github.com/chamuco/respin/tree/master/Ubuntu) although it looks like we are still waiting for a new version for 16.04 (due to a crashing issue) A possible workaround for this can be found [here.](https://github.com/chamuco/respin/issues/25)